# Problema en instalación de Angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Muy buenas, estoy teniendo problemas para crear un nuevo proyecto de angular: Después de ejecutar `ng new "nombre-app"` me da este error:

```
The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Si me pueden ayudar lo agradezco.

Comment: Falta algo más de información: parece que un fichero no pudo ser accedido pero en lo que has puesto en la pregunta no aparece el nombre de dicho fichero. Podrías pegar todo el texto que te aparece al ejecutar el comando?. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para que comprendas qué es un [mcve] y por qué es útil para ayudarte

Comment: Accede a tu CMD como Administrador y ejecuta de nuevo el comando de instalación, asegúrate de tener nodejs instalado.